# Does Android have the equivalent of a JPanel?

Tags: java, android, view, panel

Is there an Android equivalent to Java's panel? I need something with a set size that I can add different views in dynamically. Is there such a technique?

I'm basically wanting a blank area with a set size in xml code where I can add buttons later through the activity. The reason for adding later is the number of buttons and size of the buttons will range dramatically, but still needing the area to fill.

Comment: There are couple of them equivalent to JPanel like RelativeLayout, LinearLayout and AbsoluteLayout. What are you trying to achieve so we can pin point to you to a better view.

Comment: Even I also wants to know the same thing ....

Comment: @Sana I think layouts are different from JPanel , on JPanel we can implement many layouts .

Comment: You can add custom layouts on the parent layout to give a JPanel look to your app but AFAIK there isn't a JPanel class from Android OS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a JPanel class in Android but you can use layouts just as effectively. Check out this [link.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)